# How can I figure out the number of rows a Database has using MySqlDataReader?

Tags: c#, mysql, database, winforms

I am trying to figure out how to Query a MySql database for how many rows it has and for every row in the database I want to add an integer to the ID list. I am only getting 1 row returned when I run this code when I know I have more rows than that, I do not know how to user DataReader very well any advice on how I can simply figure out the number of rows that are in the database would be much appreciated.

```
    MySqlConnection Conn = new MySqlConnection(myConnectionString);
    MySqlDataReader mdr;
    public static List<int> AppointmentIDList = new List<int>();

    public void FillList()
    {
        Conn.Open();
        string Query = "SELECT * FROM U05lUM.appointment;";
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(Query, Conn);
        mdr = command.ExecuteReader();
        if (mdr.Read())
        {
            if (mdr.HasRows)
            {
                foreach(int id in mdr.GetInt32("appointmentId").ToString())
                {

                    AppointmentIDList.Add(id);

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only reading one row of your result set.

Instead of

```
if (mdr.Read())
```

you should use

```
while (mdr.Read())
```

You should change your SQL to say `SELECT appointmentId FROM U05lUM.appointment;`. It's wasteful and slow to read all the columns (with `SELECT *`) from the table when all you want is the single column.

`mdr.HasRows` will always be true inside `if (mdr.Read())` or `while (mdr.Read())` blocks. You just read a row, so the resultset definitely has rows.

Your `foreach(int id in mdr.GetInt32("appointmentId").ToString())` does not do what you want. It generates a value for each character in the string you made from the appointmentId.

And, the `SqlDataReader` object called `mdr` needs to be cleaned up (`Dispose`d) after use. That happens automatically with `using(){}`.

So I suggest this code.

```
    ...
    string Query = "SELECT appointmentId FROM U05lUM.appointment;";
    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(Query, Conn);
    using (SqlDataReader resultSet = command.ExecuteReader()) 
    {
        while (resultSet.Read())
        {
            int id = resultSet.GetInt32("appointmentId")
            AppointmentIDList.Add(id);
        }
    }
```

This won't be fast if your table is large, because your query must scan through every row of the table. The whole point of SQL is to let you handle datasets orders of magnitude larger than your RAM. You should consider designing your program so it doesn't have to read every row unless absolutely necessary.

If all you want is an exact count of the number of rows, you can use `COUNT(*)` . This gets you the count of rows in your table

```
    ...
    int rowCount;
    string Query = "SELECT COUNT(*) rowCount FROM U05lUM.appointment;";
    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(Query, Conn);
    using (SqlDataReader resultSet = command.ExecuteReader()) 
    {
        if (resultSet.Read())   // THIS result set has only one row.
        {
            rowCount = resultSet.GetInt32("rowCount")
        }
    }
```

Your DBMS is smart about how it handles `COUNT(*)`.  `MAX(appointmentId)` might also work. It could be different from the row count if there are some missing `appointmentId` values in your table. That could happen if some rows were deleted.

Answer (score 2):

You can use another query. The query could be

```cs
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("Select Count(*) FROM U05lUM.appointment;", Conn);
Conn.Open()
int rows = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
Conn.Close();
```

This would return the amount of rows that are in the 'U05lUM.appointment' database. You can also use some 'WHERE' statements if you want to further your count.